# Why is my website question off-topic? Where should I ask then?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I just posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1570071/exactly-what-is-a-proxy-site) question and readily it gets flagged as off-topic. The question is about websites that work as proxies. *Super User* seems to me a good place to ask, but anyway suppose that it's not true: where should I ask then? Surely not on *Stack Overflow* since my question is not about programming; *Server Fault* is not ok either since my question is not about managing servers; and *Web Application* as well as *Web Master* are not ok either.

So where should I ask?

Answer (score 4):

Per the help center [on topic](https://superuser.com/help) page:

> and it is **not about** …
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

Another line for other off topic items includes the clarification

> ... except insofar as they interface with your computer,

Your question is not about how it interacts with your browser, it is about how the website works itself and as such is off topic. It has nothing to do with *your* computer hardware or software.

There is [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) but your problem isn't really about *using* a web application either, it is about the internals of a website, how it works and what it does.

The problem is that any given site can work in any way from outright copying websites to simply buffering requests and any combination in-between and it is impossible to say, broadly speaking, that they all do one or another method or haven't come up with a new way of working. The only people who know how their site works is the people who made it.

There isn't always a Stack Exchange site where a question fits. Sometimes it just doesn't fit any sites on the network at all and we have never claimed to be able to have sites for every single field of human expertise.

Comment: Your answer seems unhelpful. And on top of that, even if of course this site cannot include all human knowledge, my answer is not so atypical. The fact that there isn't a place where I can ask such question should be an indication that maybe a chance in rules is needed. Or at least the creation of a new sub-site is needed.

Comment: You are fully free to suggest and promote a site at https://area51.stackexchange.com/. Just because there isn't a site for something doesn't mean that other sites *must* accept questions that they have already decided are off topic. It does not follow at all that there not being a place already means that someone else needs to change to accept something that is contrary to their chosen field.

Comment: I would also contest my answer being unhelpful. It *is* helpful in that it states clearly *why* your question is not on topic here and was closed. I cannot suggest anywhere you *could* ask it because Stack Exchange, as far as I know, does not have a site for such questions. There are many other networks and knowledgebases on the internet.

Comment: @Noumeno - Just because you don't agree with the answer you have received does not mean it is unhelpful.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason, I think it is too broad rather than off-topic